# What causes npm could not resolve errors?

Tags: node.js, npm, eslint, npm-install

I have existing project that I tried installing package via `npm install`.

I cloned my project again thinking that it would fix, but every time I run `npm install` I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: eslint-plugin-import@2.24.1
npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.20.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   dev eslint@"^8.20.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint@">= 4.12.1" from babel-eslint@10.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/babel-eslint
npm ERR!     dev babel-eslint@"^10.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   3 more (eslint-config-prettier, eslint-plugin-prettier, eslint-utils)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer eslint@"^2 || ^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7.2.0" from eslint-plugin-import@2.24.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-plugin-import
npm ERR!   dev eslint-plugin-import@"^2.23.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer eslint-plugin-import@"^2.22.1" from eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR!   1 more (eslint-config-airbnb-base)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^2 || ^3 || ^4 || ^5 || ^6 || ^7.2.0" from eslint-plugin-import@2.24.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/eslint-plugin-import
npm ERR!     dev eslint-plugin-import@"^2.23.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer eslint-plugin-import@"^2.22.1" from eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR!     1 more (eslint-config-airbnb-base)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I have no idea what is going on.

1. what is the reason for this error?
2. how can I get rid of it?
3. is it the eslint that I have to remove to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

this error can when you cannot install npm on the right folder this answer will help your sir......
otherwise your will try this
**npm install --legacy-peer-deps then**
*it adds this in my package-lock.json*

"node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter": {
"version": "5.7.0",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/-/react-native-adapter-5.7.0.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-L557/+sc8ZKJVgo1734HF1QNCxrt/fpqdmdNgySJT+kErux/AJNfPq3flsK0fyJduVmniTutYIMyW48cFoPKDA==",
"dependencies": {
"invariant": "^2.2.4",
"lodash": "^4.5.0"
},
"peerDependencies": {
"react-native": "*",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.7"
}
},

...

"@unimodules/react-native-adapter": {
"version": "5.7.0",
"resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/-/react-native-adapter-5.7.0.tgz",
"integrity": "sha512-L557/+sc8ZKJVgo1734HF1QNCxrt/fpqdmdNgySJT+kErux/AJNfPq3flsK0fyJduVmniTutYIMyW48cFoPKDA==",
"requires": {
"invariant": "^2.2.4",
"lodash": "^4.5.0"
}
},

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for it is that you have some dependency, which has a peer dependency of specific version. Now, in your package.json you have another version of this peer dependency, so npm tells you this.

You have 2 options:

- Use in your package.json dependencies that are required by the problematic package
- Use --legacy-peer-deps flag or set this setting in `.npmrc` file to be `true`, which will ignore the peer dependency requirement and can possible break your code.

Comment: when I use --legacy-peer-deps, I can install it once, but every package I try to install I always have to run it with --legacy-peer-deps, how can I get rid of it forever?

Comment: Create `.npmrc` file in your project and put there `legacy-peer-deps=true`